# Count number of rows on web table Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a web table in a page which has only one attribute class. I want to identify number of rows in that table. I am using below code which runs but gives me the count of all web tables which have their parent class as OverviewTable:

[image]

```
int rowCount=IE1.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='overviewTable']/tbody/tr")).size();
```

please also see the screenshot.

Comment: You should have a count method, not size.

Comment: It appears to be the first table in the page with the class 'overviewTable'. Try this xpath -- "//table[@class='overviewTable'][1]/tbody/tr"

Comment: //table[@class='overviewTable'][1]/tbody/tr - this works TY :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that rowCount is a `List` of type `WebElement`, then you can you use all the methods available to `List`

```
List<WebElement> rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='overviewTable']/tbody/tr"));
System.out.println("Num rows: " + rowCount .size());
```